# Django display number of objects in the account model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently creating a rest api. 
I have an account and  book model. The book model has a foreign key to the account.
I want to add a number_of_books field in the account model which has an int representing how many books the user has. What is the best way to implement this? Do I need to calculate from the client side? Should I create a middleware that does this?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

You can `.annotate(..)` your `Account` model, with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Account.objects.annotate(
    number_of_books=Count('book')
)
```

The `Account` objects that arise from *this* queryset will contain an extra attribute `.number_of_books`.

Comment: Thank you, will definitely look into this concept